# Wait for the presence of either of two locators in Playwright Typescript using Promise.race()

Tags: typescript, playwright, playwright-test

I am new to Typescript world exploring Playwright for Test Automation. There is a case where, some loading happens and I get either of 2 element - Validated, Failed. In Selenium, I prefer to go with WebDriverWait and stop the loop at once any one element appears.
In Typescript, I learnt that we could use something like Promise.race() but I couldn't make it work.
Here's my code:

```js
public waitForFinalStatus = async (): Promise<Boolean> => {     
    const [failed, validated] = await Promise.race([
        this.locFailed().waitFor({ timeout: 120000 }).then(() => "Failed"),
        this.locValidated().waitFor({ timeout: 120000 }).then(() => "Passed")
    ]);

    return validated === "Passed";
}
```

Both failed, validated statuses are getting values like "E", "C" which I couldn't comprehend. I thought that, when its passed, value "Passed" would be passed and the other one would have `undefined`.

I have one more question here. Lets say, the `Validated` element appeared. After the wait time of 120 seconds, `waitFor` on locFailed would fail which should throw error, isn't it? Without proper try catch won't it affect the program flow? In case of Selenium Java, this is handled internally WebDriverWait by ignoring NotFoundException so that the exception thrown by element not being available is handled. As far as I understood, `waitFor` just throw error if element is not found within the specified conditions and throws error if not found. A bit of info on this concept would be enlightening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[hardkoded's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77819978/8583511) probably fits your particular problem better, but in general you should know that `Promise.race` returns a Promise that resolves to a single value, not an array. In your case, `Promise.race` would resolve to either `"Failed"` or `"Passed"`. With the array assignment, you are simply getting the first two characters of the returned string.

See, for example, [MDN's documentation for `Promise.race`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race).

> After the wait time of 120 seconds, waitFor on locFailed would fail which should throw error, isn't it? Without proper try catch won't it affect the program flow?

`Promise.race` attaches success and error callbacks to all promises you pass it, meaning, if those promises reject, that is **not** an unhandled promise rejection and therefore will not lead to an error or process exit.

If, for example, `locValidated().waitFor()` resolves, then the Promise returned by `Promise.race` will resolve with `"Passed"`. If later, `locFailed().waitFor()` rejects, nothing will happen.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `or` locator and use it to assert.

```
await assertThat(locFailed.or(locValidated)).isVisible();
```

Comment: Thanks @hardkoded. Just wondering how would I know which locator is visible in this approach? Whether it’s Failed or Validated?

Comment: @AhamedAbdulRahman good thing about `assertThat` is that it will wait for a period of time until one of those two elements is visible. Once you know you do have one of those two, you can use the `isVisible` function that won't fail! if the element is not there: `locFailed.isVisible()`. `isVisible` doesn't have a wait timeout.

Comment: Now, I got it. Thanks @hardkoded. This is also a good approach. Sorry I can't make 2 answers as accepted.